# Using `django-allauth` to let users sign in with Twitter and tweet through the app

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-allauth

I'm trying to use `django-allauth` for Twitter sign-in in my Django app. I notice that when I do the sign-in process, Twitter says that this app will NOT be able to post tweets. I do want to be able to post tweets. How do I add this permission?

Answer (score 0):

I see now that I simply needed to define my app as "read & write" in the Twitter admin UI.